Why does the Snap install of Firefox opens links in background on Ubuntu?
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. Since a reinstallation of Firefox 128.0.2 (snap remove firefox ; snap install firefox) it opens links from other applications in the background.
When I click a link in Slack or anywhere else, a system notification pops up saying "Page xyz is ready." But I would like Firefox to come to the foreground with that page.

When I install Firefox via apt and use the exact same profile, it correctly comes to the foreground.

When I set Chrome as my default browser, it also correctly comes to the foreground.


I tried setting tabs.loadInBackground to false, but that doesn't change anything:


In Firefox About:preferences

search on link.
Set When you open a link, image or media in a new tab, switch to it immediately


BTW, you're not limited to using the Snap version of Firefox. If you prefer, uninstall the Snap version (keeping a copy of your profile) and install from Mozilla as PPA. (On PC's I maintain, I find Snap apps slow to start, require large downloads and more disk space, and are often not updated to the latest native version.)
Also, I have the following in userChrome.css to avoid opening a new tab on middle-mouse button-click, which might influence other settings:
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */
/* Disable New Tab on MiddleClick */
#tabbrowser-tabs .arrowscrollbox-scrollbox{pointer-events: none} .tabbrowser-tab,.tabs-newtab-button{pointer-events: auto}
#TabsToolbar .toolbar-items {pointer-events: none}


This is on. This is the same "loadInBackground" setting I mentioned in my post, btw. This setting is for what happens when you middle-click a link within Firefox. It doesn't have any influence on what happens when you click a link in another app.

@FelixDombek, when I middle-click on a link in Firefox 128.0.3, it jumps to that new tab immediately. Perhaps it has to do with a userChrome.css addition I've added to the answer, or not.

I don't know how to be more precise: My whole question is NOT about links within FIrefox. It's about Firefox's behavior on my system when it is the default browser and I click a link in Slack (or any other app).
